What is the difference between RtlAddFunctionTable and RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable?
The RtlAddFunctionTable  is used to dynamically install a funciton table in order to handle SEH exceptions.I have used it on custom loader, everything's fine. I was not able to find much information about RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable which is an undocumented internal function, but it seems to do the same job as the first function.
Has anyone any idea what is the difference between those two?

Why would you want to use an internal undocumented function, when you have a public and documented one that seems to do the same ? I would consider the first an implementation detail that you should not be using anyway.

@wohlstad I was just curious, I was not considering to use it on a real example.

http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=8&a=2&p=20

Previous versions of MSDN (already deleted) showed RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable: Statically Installing Function Tables
In contrast to RtlAddFunctionTable, RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable is used to statically install a Function Table for a function or module. This means that the Function Table is added to the system at compile time, rather than at runtime. This approach is useful when the Function Table is known in advance and does not need to be modified during the execution of the program. If you still wanna more info about it. I can make an answer.

@Torrecto-MSFT is there any way that what he https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78600525/how-to-fill-exception-record-properly-for-a-rtlunwindex-call tried to do, could be done with RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable ?

RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable is used for x86 executables, while RtlAddFunctionTable is used for 64-bit. That is the main difference, I think.
You can see it a lot in custom DLL loaders, where in the same place they call either RtlAddFunctionTable for 64-bit images or RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable for 32-bit images.
Also, the RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable function signature have changed quite a lot over the years. For example, on Windows 7 the arguments of the function were different than they are now, so handling this for multiple Windows versions is kinda annoying. You can find a lot of stuff about this on the internet, just search. Or on GitHub.
For example this project is just an amazing showcase of how the Windows loader works. And it also uses the mentioned RtlInsertInvertedFunctionTable function.
https://github.com/bb107/MemoryModulePP

hey I don't think thats quite right.Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78600525/how-to-fill-exception-record-properly-for-a-rtlunwindex-call
RtlAddFunctionTable works in dynamics loaders fine with pure seh exceptions but fails with c++.
